# .toLowerCase() / .toUpperCase() not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get better at javascript through codewars.com katas, and I came across an exercice in which things like `element[i]=element[i].toLowerCase()` doesn't change anything at all.
I would like to have some help with my code, here is the exercice's instructions followed by my code:
(Please note that I'm not very experienced with JS so the code may not be perfect at all)

> A string is considered to be in title case if each word in the string
> is either:
>
> - (a) capitalised (that is, only the first letter of the word
>   is in upper case) or
> - (b) considered to be an exception and put entirely into lower case unless it is the first word, which is always capitalised.
>
> Write a function that will convert a string into title case, given an optional list of exceptions (minor words). The list of minor words will be given as a string with each word separated by a space.
> Your function should ignore the case of the minor words string -- it should behave in the same way even if the case of the minor word string is changed.
>
> Arguments:
>
> - First argument (required): the original string to be converted.
> - Second argument (optional): space-delimited list of minor words that must always be lowercase except for the first word in the string. The JavaScript/CoffeeScript tests will pass `undefined` when this argument is unused.

```js
function titleCase(title, minorWords) {
  if(title.length==0){return ""}
  var titlesplit = title.split(" ")
  if(minorWords){
    minorWords=minorWords.split(" ")
  }
  var solutionstring = ""
  titlesplit.forEach(element => myfunction(element,minorWords))
  solutionstring[0] = solutionstring[0].toUpperCase()
  return solutionstring

  function myfunction(element,minorWords){
    var elementlength= element.length
    var i=0
    if(minorWords && minorWords.includes(element)){
      for(i;i<elementlength;i++){
        element[i]=element[i].toLowerCase()
      }
    }else {
      for(i;i<elementlength;i++){
        if(i==0){element[i]=element[i].toUpperCase()}
        else{element[i]=element[i].toLowerCase()}
      }
    }
    if(solutionstring.length==0){solutionstring=solutionstring+element}else{solutionstring=solutionstring+" "+element}
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you return in "myfunction" ?

Comment: Strings are immutable. You cannot do `var str = "abc"; str[0] = "d";` - it will not work.

Comment: That aside, it looks like you just want `function titleCase(title, minorWords) {return title.toLowerCase().replace(/\w+/g, word=>minorWords && minorWords.indexOf(word) > -1 ? word : word[0].toUppercase()+word.slice(1));}` -- assuming you actually pass in an array of `minorWords` rather than a space-separated string.

Comment: Why is  `function myfunction()` _in_ `titleCase()`? And why is it "after" `return ...`?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, Strings are immutable in JavaScript.
Additionally, for searching use Maps instead of includes.
Likewise you can see what Set in JavaScript is and easily use Set here.

Added comments for you better understanding.

```
function titleCase(title, minorWords) {
    // Use === for comparison
    // Prefer using curly braces even for single statements
    if (title.length === 0) {
        return "";
    }
    var titlesplit = title.split(" ");
    // Maps/Objects give O(1) search compared to arrays O(n)
    // Key,value pairs - similar to dictionary
    var minorWordsMap = {};
    minorWords.split(" ").forEach(i => minorWordsMap[i.toLowerCase()] = true);
    
    var finalWords = titlesplit.map((element, index) => convertCase(element, index));
    finalWords[0] = toPascalCase(finalWords[0]);
    
    return finalWords.join(" ");

    function toPascalCase(s) {
        s = s.split("");
        s[0] = s[0].toUpperCase();
        return s.join("");
    }

    function convertCase(element, index) {
        const lElement = element.toLowerCase();
        // If element is part of exception words, ignore
        if(index !== 0 && minorWordsMap[lElement]) {
            return element;
        }
        // If first element or not in exception list, send Title case
        return toPascalCase(lElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I learned a lot.
It seems to run perfectly except that exception words who are not in first position don't get put in lower cases, does it have something to do with your condition in convertCase?

See error:
Gave title="the QUICK bRoWn fOX", minorWords="xyz fox quick the". Expected "The quick Brown fox" but got "The QUICK Brown fOX".

Comment: Nevermind it's just the return that should be lElement instead of element, thanks anyway :)